# 'int' object has no attribute '_committed' Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to add 5 image field to my table, 3 are required and 2 are not .. I get the error when I try to upload only 3 images,, but everything is fine when I upload 5 images. here are my files :

**models.py** where the main table is created :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # custom validators
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

    # fields
    dress_name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, verbose_name='نوع الفستان',)
    dress_rate = models.ForeignKey(Rate, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, verbose_name='تصنيف الفستان',)
    dress_size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='مقاس الفستان', blank=False)
    dress_color = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='لون الفستان', blank=False)
    dress_description = models.TextField(max_length=800, verbose_name=' وصف إضافى للفستان', blank=False, default='وصف الفستان')
    dress_image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='الصورة الأساسية للفستان',
                                     help_text='لا يمكنك تركها فارغة',default=1)
    dress_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='صورة إضافية ',default=1)
    dress_image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='صورة إضافة ',default=1)
    dress_image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافة ',default=1)
    dress_image5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافة ',default=1)
    dress_action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='الفستان معروض لل ',
                                     help_text='للبيع او للإيجار ', blank=False)
    dress_price = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='السعر', blank=False)
    dress_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric], verbose_name='رقم الهاتف ', blank=False)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    created_username = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='unknown')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    dress_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dress_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dress_town = models.ForeignKey(Town, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='المحافظة', blank=False)
```

**views.py** where the view for adding the item in the table :

```
def dress_add(request):
    current_user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        add_dress_form = AddDressForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if add_dress_form.is_valid():
            model_instance = add_dress_form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.created_by = current_user.name
            model_instance.created_username = current_user.email
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('dress_confirm')
    else:
        add_dress_form = AddDressForm()

    context = {
        'add_dress_form': add_dress_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/dress_add.html', context)
```

**forms.py** where to form to add item is created:

```
class AddDressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['created_by', 'created_at', 'dress_active', 'dress_special', 'created_username']
```

**HTML** :

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="AddDressForm" align="right" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ add_dress_form.non_field_errors }}
{% for field in add_dress_form %}
    <span style="color: red; ">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    {{ field.label_tag }}&nbsp;{% if field.field.required %}<span style="color: red; font-size: xx-small; ">مطلوب</span> {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col" align="right">
        {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
```

and here is the **Traceback** for the error i see:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dress/add

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['social_django',
 'storages',
 'django_filters',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'fostania_web_app.apps.FostaniaWebAppConfig']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\django\fostania\fostania_web_app\views.py" in dress_add
  67.             model_instance.save()

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  842.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  880.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1125.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1282.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1235.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1235.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1234.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_save_val
  1184.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  285.         if file and not file._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dress/add
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: Show full error text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set an `ImageField` to have a default value of `1`, which is an integer. You need to change it to a sensible value, something like `'image/default.jpg'`.

You may want to consider using [`django-imagekit`](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which helps with managing images for django models.